# Should try/catch be inside or outside a using block?

Tags: c#, exception

The `using` block is shorthand for `try/catch/finally` I believe. In my code I have been putting a `try/catch` block *inside* the `using` block, so that I can catch and log exceptions using my own logger.

I have recently been wondering if the `try` should be on the outside, thus encapsulating the `using` block, or not.

To my mind I have previously been worried that if an exception is thrown then the `using` block will not `Dispose()` of my resource because it has jumped out of the block and into the catch handler. But I may be wrong.

Could somebody please clarify which is the correct way to use both `using` and `try/catch` together?

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetData(string x, int y)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        try
        {
            // do stuff

            return response.Result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // Something has gone badly wrong so we'll need to throw

            // Log the info

            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not necessary to use try/catch if you have a `using` block. It is especially not necessary to catch an exception and immediately rethrow it. If all you want to do is log exceptions, subscribe to the `AppDomain.UnhandledException` event.

Comment: In this case I would also put it inside the using block. But as others said there's no correct way to do it.

Comment: The `using` block is not shorthand for try/catch/finally. A `using` block is used to automatically dispose of an object once it is not needed anymore.

Comment: Would it automatically dispose if you were to throw; inside it? What about a goto; ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`using` block is used to ensure the disposal (changed from ambiguous "immediate disposal" term to disposal as suggested by [Mr. James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82586/james)) of the objects declared in the `using` statement as soon as the code is out of the `using` block. It is *not exactly* the shorthand for `try/catch/finally`. (Note that [the compiler interprets it as try-finally](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) however)

In your example

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
} //client will be disposed at any time after this line
```

Depends on the case, you may consider of putting `try-catch` block inside or outside of `using` block.

For example, if you do not need to use the item in the `using` declaration multiple times (edit: what I mean by this is if you need the item **both** in the `try` and in the `catch` block - thanks for input by [Mr. Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray)) - that is, you only need it in `try`, I would suggest to use `using` block inside of the `try` block.

Translated to your case, it depends on whether `var client` is intended to be used both for the `try` and the `catch` blocks. If it is, the `using` should be outside of the `try-catch` block. Else, it should be inside of the `try` block.

In general, as a rule of thumb, if the item is used both in the `try` and `catch` block, then declare `using` only once outside of the `try-catch`

Comment: I'd be wary of the term "*immediate disposal*", I get what you mean in the fact that `Dispose` will be called but that certainly doesn't guarantee immediate disposal in terms of garbage collection.

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say "redeclaration"? It is only declared *once* here, inside of the using statement.

Comment: @James ah, yes, for the lack of better term... Any better suggestion? I am open to it. Else, I would just put up a note?

Comment: @CodyGray I mean, if you need it both in the try and in the catch block... then it needs to be re-declared...

Comment: @Ian I'd literally just get rid of the word "*immediate*"

Comment: @James ok, suggestion noted. My answer is updated. Thanks again.

Comment: "*It is not the shorthand for `try/catch/finally`*"....hmm, that's not what the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) say, in fact, they pretty much say that's *exactly* the case - "*You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler.*"

Comment: @James can `using` throw exception in the `catch`? I think what the sample shows is there is `try-finally` - not `try-catch-finally`.

Comment: @Ian again, I've probably misconstrued your answer. It sounded like you were saying the `using` doesn't use a `try` construct at all here when in fact it does use a `try...finally`.

Answer (score 6):

It really depends on what resource it is you are worried about being disposed - if you are referring to `client` you should be fine. I'll explain why...

> To my mind I have previously been worried that if an exception is thrown then the using block will not Dispose() of my resource because it has jumped out of the block and into the catch handler. But I may be wrong.

That's not how it works, the compiler will likely rewrite your code (probably more efficiently) like so:

```
try
{
    try
    {
        // do stuff
        return response.Result;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Something has gone badly wrong so we'll need to throw
        // Log the info
        throw;
    }
}
finally
{
    if (client != null)
        client.Dispose();
}
```

Under *normal* circumstances a `finally` block will always execute which means, even if you catch/rethrow an exception inside the `using`, your `Dispose` call will be triggered.

So from a technical point of view, inside vs outside doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 0):

Either way will work. Using blocks are guaranteed to always call the `Dispose()` method on exit - this is true even for stack un-ravelling for exceptions being caught further down the stack.

Look at [using Statement (C# Reference)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

> The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object. You can achieve the same result by putting the object inside a try block and then calling Dispose in a finally block; in fact, this is how the using statement is translated by the compiler. The code example earlier expands to the following code at compile time (note the extra curly braces to create the limited scope for the object):

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct way" on it, only guidelines. However I myself try to localize every exception or any code as far as possible, meaning you should an exception where it can be thrown, but somewhere outside, at least as long as you do not have to let your exception bubble through different layers.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would put the try/catch/finally inside the `using` block.
The reason for this is simply that the `using` block itself will not throw an exception, at least not from my experience. So for the sake of simplicity, I would deal with Exceptions where they occur.

Answer (score 0):

As `using` compiles down to try/finally, just use try/catch/finally. ["A finally block always executes, regardless of whether an exception is thrown."](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/exceptions/how-to-use-finally-blocks)

```cs
var client = new HttpClient();
try
{
    // do stuff

    return response.Result;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Something has gone badly wrong so we'll need to throw

    // Log the info

    throw;
}
finally
{
    if (client != null)
        client.Dispose();
}
```

The finally block could also be reduced to `client?.Dispose();` with c# 6 and above.

All that said, HttpClient is a special case. Yes it is disposable but you should be careful about creating and disposing on the fly particularly in a long lived application, and may be better using a single shared instance.

https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/
https://medium.com/@nuno.caneco/c-httpclient-should-not-be-disposed-or-should-it-45d2a8f568bc